# Teradata : BTEQ Import Invalid Date Issue

Tags: date, import, teradata

I am trying to port data from a flat file to TD via BTEQ.
The table definition is :

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE _module_execution_log 
 (
  system_id INTEGER,
  process_id INTEGER,
  module_id INTEGER,
  julian_dt INTEGER,
  referral_dt DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD',
  start_dt_tm TIMESTAMP(6),
  end_dt_tm TIMESTAMP(6),
  ref_s_cnt INTEGER,
  ref_d_cnt INTEGER)
  PRIMARY INDEX ( module_id );
```

Following are 2 sample records that i am trying to load in the table :
`1|1|30|2007073|Mar 14 2007 12:00:00:000AM|Mar 15 2007  1:27:00:000PM|Mar 15 2007  1:41:08:686PM|0|0
1|1|26|2007073|Mar 14 2007 12:00:00:000AM|Mar 15 2007  1:27:00:000PM|Mar 15 2007  1:59:40:620PM|0|0`

Snippet for my BTEQ script

```
USING 
(   system_id INTEGER
    ,process_id INTEGER
    ,module_id INTEGER
    ,julian_dt INTEGER
    ,referral_dt DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    ,start_dt_tm TIMESTAMP
    ,end_dt_tm TIMESTAMP
    ,ref_s_cnt INTEGER
    ,ref_d_cnt INTEGER
)        

INSERT INTO _module_execution_log
(   system_id
    ,process_id
    ,module_id
    ,julian_dt
    ,referral_dt
    ,start_dt_tm
    ,end_dt_tm
    ,ref_s_cnt
    ,ref_d_cnt
)
VALUES ( 
    :system_id
    ,:process_id
    ,:module_id
    ,:julian_dt
    ,:referral_dt
    ,:start_dt_tm
    ,:end_dt_tm
    ,:ref_s_cnt
    ,:ref_d_cnt);
```

I get the following error during import :

```
*** Failure 2665 Invalid date.
           Statement# 1, Info =5


*** Failure 2665 Invalid date.
           Statement# 1, Info =5
```

The issue is surely with the exported date in 5th column. I cannot modify the export query.
 I tried the following in the bteq but still failed : 
 `cast(cast(substr(:referral_dt,1,11) as date format 'MMMBDDBYYYY') as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD')`

Answer (score 1):

Your data is pipe-delimited variable length characters and the USING should match the input data, e.g.

```
system_id VARCHAR(11)
referral_dt VARCHAR(26)
```

The VarChars will be automatically casted to the target datatypes using a default format. For your Timestamps you need to cast manually adding a format:

```
referral_dt (TIMESTAMP(3),FORMAT 'mmmBddByyyyBhh:mi:ss.s(3)T')
```

But this will fail for a single digit hour, Teradata always wants two digits.

If you're on TD14 you better utilize the Oracle TO_DATE/TO_TIMESTAMP UDFs which allow single digit hours:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(referral_dt,'MON DD YYYY HH:MI:SS:FF3AM')
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I am not on TD14 so the second option is ruled out. I am initially considering the referral_dt column. I would like to know why can't the substring function work and i can just pick the date as that is what is required by the referral_dt ?

Comment: Of course you can do a substring to extract the date part only. For the timestamps you need to do a CASE plus SUBSTRINGs to add the missing 0.

Comment: Hi, i thought of porting all data as varchar in a staging table on TD and then formatting it while inserting in target. This approach gave me a playground. Thanks for the inputs. Appreciate it :)

Comment: Hi dnoeth , I used TO_TIMESTAMP with 100% success for my use cases. Wanted to add that one must trim the input string. I faced this issue when i was trying to convert a string specifying time value (single hour) only. Thanks for your help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a date indicated by your data.

First 4 values expected are integer, then a date, then a timestamp:

```
system_id INTEGER,
process_id INTEGER,
module_id INTEGER,
julian_dt INTEGER,
**referral_dt DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD'**,
start_dt_tm TIMESTAMP(6), ...
```

Your data doesn't match:

```
1|1|30|2007073|Mar 14 2007 12:00:00:000AM|Mar 15 2007  1:27:00:000PM|Mar 15 2007  1:41:08:686PM|0|0
```

you are missing the date:

```
1|1|30|2007073|**????-??-??**| Mar 14 2007 12:00:00:000AM|...
```